# F-curves aren't showing for half the animation

Tags: audio, fcurves

So I'm making an audio visualizer in blender. For the first half of the animation, there are no f-curves, even though in the audio file there is music. I've checked to make sure there are no modifiers, and it is the correct audio file. Can anyone tell me what's gone wrong?
[image]

Comment: Did you set the timeline frame number to 1 when you "Baked sound to F-Curve"?  It will start the bake wherever the Current Frame is set, not automatically from frame zero or wherever you might have set an initial keyframe.